# Split date and time in a string using substring

Tags: vb.net, date, time, datagridview, substring

what is the best way to split the date and time.(See below example)
How can I do it so that column 1 with original string will be splitted into 2 columns the date and time. My problem is the string may contain a single digit in Date or Time (eg. 11/9/2018) the 9 is single digit, If I will use substring array the total count will not be the same if the date is 11/10/2018.

eg.

```
Column 1 (Date1) (original string)

11/9/201812:52:53 AM

Column 2 (Date2)

11/9/2018

Column 3 (Time1)

12:52:53 AM
```

My codes so far, I can split the date but this will only will work if I have a fixed number of character in a string.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView6.Rows.Count - 1 Step +1

Dim split(1) As String

split(0) = DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.substring(0, 8)

split(1) = DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.substring(8, 6)

DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(15).Value = split(0)

DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(16).Value = split(1)

Next
```

Comment: Don't split the `String`. Parse the `String` to a `DateTime` and then simply format that in both grid columns using appropriate format specifiers.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Can I use it even though my string doesn't have space in between the date and time?, here's the original string (11/9/201812:52:53 AM)

Comment: If you call `Date.ParseExact` or `.TryParseExact` then you specify the input format, so it can be anything you want. You can even specify multiple formats if you need to, as long as they are not ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using .ParseExact you provide the pattern for the input string.

```
Private Sub SplitDateAndTime()
    Dim input = "11/9/201812:52:53 AM"
    Dim d As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "M/d/yyyyhh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    Dim dateOnly As String = d.ToShortDateString
    Dim timeOnly As String = d.ToLongTimeString
    Debug.Print($"The date is {dateOnly} and the time is {timeOnly}")
    'result The date is 11/9/2018 and the time is 12:52:53 AM
End Sub
```

Comment: For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView6.Rows.Count - 1 Step +1Dim input = 

DataGridView6.Rows(i).Cells("Date1").Value

Dim d As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "M/d/yyyyhh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Dim dateOnly As String = d.ToShortDateString

Dim timeOnly As String = d.ToLongTimeString

DataGridView6.Rows(i).Cells("Date2").Value = dateOnly

DataGridView6.Rows(i).Cells("Time").Value = timeOnly

Next
It says "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: @preciousbetine Huh? 11/29/2018 works just the same with same pattern.

Comment: @ArdieFernandezAppleKendee Just for grins add a `.ToString` at the end of `Dim input = DataGridView6.Rows(i).Cells("Date1").Value` There is no telling how vb is interpreting the value. Also add a `Debug.Print(input)` immediately following to double check the pattern of the string. No space between data and time. Right?

Comment: @Mary, I tried it as string using only "11/9/201812:52:53 AM" as Input string, It's working but when I tried to use the datagridview It's not working, tried also the tostring which I think is the problem but no luck, all my data in the column date1 all has the same format. Also when I tried to add the tostring it says String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Could there be some hiddon white space? Maybe a `.ToString.Trim`

Comment: @Mary You're right there's a space before and after the each values of datagridview BTW I'm importing data from a Delimited Tab Notepad and passing it on the gridview and upload it to MySQL. Thank you very much.